# Unix разница между mail и mailx

Tags: unix, email

Собственно сабж. В чём разница между mail и mailx? Я вроде слышал что вся соль в пакетах, но вот точно не знаю. Спасибо

Comment: Может будет интересно почитать [mail, Mail, mailx, nail—history notes](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx_history.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В чём разница между mail и mailx?

Ни в чём:

```
[14:56:34] ~ $ ls -la /usr/bin/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 апр.   2 14:56 /usr/bin/mail -> /etc/alternatives/mail
[14:56:50] ~ $ ls -la /etc/alternatives/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 апр.   2 14:56 /etc/alternatives/mail -> /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
[14:57:01] ~ $ ls -la /usr/bin/mailx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 апр.   2 14:56 /usr/bin/mailx -> /etc/alternatives/mailx
[14:57:09] ~ $ ls -la /etc/alternatives/mailx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 апр.   2 14:56 /etc/alternatives/mailx -> /usr/bin/mail.mailutils
```

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент никакой (mailx и mail это одна программа, вызываемая с разными именами).
Исторически, mail - более старая версия, mailx - более "новая". В кавычках - потому что появилась в 1986 году.